# How to check e.result?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I want to get the `e.result` before it pumps data into my listbox..I want to check whether the `e.result` is null or have value..
My coding is like this

```
public Page1(string s)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();
    proxy.FindEmployeeCompleted += new EventHandler<FindEmployeeCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_FindEmployeeCompleted);
    proxy.FindEmployeeAsync(s);
}
void proxy_FindEmployeeCompleted(object sender, FindEmployeeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Result!=null)
    {
      listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    }
    else
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password.");
    }
}
```

but after i execute my coding, the message box didn't show up...
Is it i miss out any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void proxy_FindEmployeeCompleted(object sender, FindEmployeeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
    else if (e.Result != null)
    {
        // you can check results here. 
        if (e.Result.Any())
        {
            listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }else
        {
            // empty result, show message or whatever 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password.");
    }
}
```